# Angular Routes Lazy Loading for Nested Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following route setup for my app.routing.ts with lazy loading implement for most of my component. 
My app consists of two main parts, 'visitor can access part' and 'logged in user can access part'. 
When not logged in, the user will be blocked by AuthGuard and any of the routes such as account and admin will be blocked and re-dirrected to home

```
// app.routing.ts
const APP_ROUTE: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', },
{ path: '', component: UserLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule' },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
    ]
},
{ path: '', component: VisitorLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    { path: 'privacy-policy', loadChildren: 'app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module#PrivacyPolicyModule' },
    { path: 'terms-and-condition', loadChildren: 'app/terms-and-condition/terms-and-condition.module#TermsAndConditionModule' },
    ]
}, 
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/home'}
];


// account.routing.ts with guards
const ACOUNT_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'edit-defaults', component: AccountEditDefaultsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'change-password', component: AccountChangePasswordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

// admin.routing.ts with guards
const ADMIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard] },
    { path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard] },
];
```

The lazy loading works fine at this stage as non of the component that requires logging is loaded unless user signed in.
However, I want to improve this even more by lazy load UserLayoutComponent unless the user is signed in as it makes no sense to load anything inside that component up front.
At the moment it is imported so it is not lazy loaded

I have tried to create a user-layout.module.ts and user-layout.routing.ts and change my app.routing.ts to be

```
// app.routing.ts
const APP_ROUTE: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', },
{ path: '', loadChildren: 'app/layout/user-layout/user-layout.module#UserLayoutModule', children: [
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: 'app/account/account.module#AccountModule' },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
    ]
},
{ path: '', component: VisitorLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    { path: 'privacy-policy', loadChildren: 'app/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module#PrivacyPolicyModule' },
    { path: 'terms-and-condition', loadChildren: 'app/terms-and-condition/terms-and-condition.module#TermsAndConditionModule' },
    ]
}, 
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/home'}
];
```

I am getting this error indicating that this is the wrong approach to do it.

> children and loadChildren cannot be used together

How can I achieve lazy loading for my UserLautComponent.ts

Note that my UserLayoutComponent consists of navbar, side menu and some initial loads to get user information once logged in

Comment: probably you would take a look into [ui router for angular 2](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/)